# Haystack solr setting importance level

Tags: python, search, solr

I can't seem to find it in the documentation. How would I set the level of importance for each Index's search attributes. For example purposes lets say I have a model Note with search index NoteIndex,

The model:

```
class Note(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     body = models.TextField()
```

The index:

```
 class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
     text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
     body = indexes.CharFiled(model_attr = 'body')
     author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
     pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')
```

How would I set it up so that my objects get indexed in such a way that a query with a match to author is more important (scored higher) than a query with a match to body no matter how many times the query is matched to the body. Since solr is running a BM25f (not sure) document relevance search a possible solution seems to be to add author in the text document many times. But this is an inelegant solution.

I was wondering if haystack/python solves this problem at all.

Comment: In solr you can boos field at index time or you can boost a field at query time: the second option is more flexible, see the 'qf' parameter here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser

Answer (score 1):

Mauro's answer led me to search for the term 'boosting' in haystack. Turns out that haystack does support this and we can just add boosts right in the model:

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/boost.html